# Schema types for Google enhancement Event & Video

Tags: seo, google-search, schema.org, structured-data, json-ld

I'm working to publish the meta information for a SaaS platform emitting live events, video broadcasts live shopping sessions.

In order to take advantage of Google search enhancements for each upcoming event, I selected the schema object [Event](https://schema.org/Event) and generate the JSON-D info on the page. However, when the event starts, technically it becomes a video stream, and as I understand from the [google dev docs](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/video#broadcast-event), [in order to be eligible for display with a LIVE badge](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/video#:%7E:text=be%20eligible%20for%20display%20with%20a%20live%20badge) I think I need to expose the JSON-D info as a VideoObject with the selected BroadcastEvent properties nested (`publication.startDate`, `publication.endDate`, `publication.isLiveBroadcast`).

What do you think is the best/valid approach?:

1. Published as Event, turning into Video with nested BroadcastEvent properties once started live.
2. Published as a [BroadcastEvent](https://schema.org/BroadcastEvent) all the time. publication.isLiveBroadcast change to true once started.
3. Published as BroadcastEvent, then turning into Video with nested BroadcastEvent properties once started.

The only problem I have with the BroadcastEvent object is a property named `broadcastOfEvent`, I'm not sure if it can be null which will be my case if selected, because this page is referring to the event that is a broadcast by itself. So in cases 2 and 3 how should I proceed?